# Windows Update Search Fails Silently

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update

I have a Windows Vista computer.

When clicking on Windows Update, I click on Search, and it shows the progress bar for a few seconds then returns to the main page.

There is a red logo with an `X`, but no error message. 
It says the last search was in 2012. Every time I click it does the same thing.

[image: Windows Update]

[(Full size image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6oZo.jpg)

Comment: By the way the computer runs MS Windows Vista Home Basic 32-bit SP2 according to CCleaner

Comment: I have this problem myself. Same OS too.  Did arielnmz's answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the *Windows Update* service is correctly started and running, chances are that this is the cause of your issue:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run `services.msc` (you'll need admin rights).
2. Scroll down to the `Windows Update` service.
3. `Right click` it and select `Properties`.
4. Click on the buttons to `stop` and then `start` the service again, or press `restart` (if available).
5. You can also change the startup type to either `Manual`, `Automatic` or `Automatic (delayed)` but **not** `Disabled`; this prevents you to even start the service *manually*, though if this was the issue, the client would complain about being *unable to start the service*.